# java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered ClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = xx.MyClass)

Tags: android, serialization, service, bundle, classnotfoundexception

Couple days ago I refactored my code so that when starting my service I put a custom class in the Bundle

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
  private double lat;
  private double lng
}
```

I had made the mistake to NOT put a serialVersionUID and my ACRA got hammered by thousands of exception  saying '.. cannot deserialize xx with id=xxx'
So what I did is push a version that has a serialVersionUID=-1 in MyClass but the problem didn't seem to be solved as now the error was saying something like
'... canot deserialize xx with id=-1 becuse was id was xxx'

So what I did is delete the MyClass and created a MyClass2 because I thought it was gonna just ignore the old MyClass and directly use the new MyClass2. Well no.. I still had error related to these desesialisation problem.. So I gave up and instead of passing a custom object a directly pass the two primitive in the bundle..

But even after doing that.. i still got this ghost MyClass hunting me!!!
And the worse part is the MyClass doesn't even exist in my project anymore! So I have no idea what is Android doing right now, no idea why is it still trying to deserialize a class that is not even the code anymore...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service xx.MyService@d2ef12e with Intent { act=ACTION_START flg=0x4 cmp=cc/.MyService (has extras) }: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered ClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = xx.MyClass)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1489)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered ClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = xx.MyClass)
at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2543)
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2346)
at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2645)
at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
at android.os.BaseBundle.get(BaseBundle.java:281)
at xxMyService.onStartCommand(ScanService.java:184)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3067)
... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xx.MyClass
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
at android.os.Parcel$2.resolveClass(Parcel.java:2529)
```

Note I personally never managed to reproduce this error... But i'm seeing it bombarding my ACRA log by hundred of different devices